# I'm encountering difficulties implementing a camera that follows a moving object in Pygame. Are there common approaches to address this?

Tags: pygame, camera, physics

I have a physics simulation of the solar system and want to add a camera function that lets you focus on a certain planet and zoom in on it, but because of gravity, i cant make the object stay in one spot, so i am trying to create a camera system.

I was trying to make a camera system but it just ended up crashing the program, so i removed it.

```
import pygame
import math
import sys, os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
planets = []
WIDTH, HEIGHT =  1600, 900
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Planet Simulation")
count=0
WHITE = (227,187,118)
REAL_WHITE = (255,255,255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BLUE = (79,76,176)
RED = (244,138,54)
DARK_GREY = (104, 105, 109)
ORANGE = (201,144,57)
SATURN = (234,214,184)
URANUS = (209, 231, 231)
NEPTUNE = (91,93,223)
FLAG=False
CLICKFLAG=False
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 16)
# atmos = (["jupiter",""], [earth, "air"])


class Planet:
  AU = 149.6e6 * 1000
  G = 6.67428e-11
  ZOOM=250


  SCALE = ZOOM / AU  # 1AU = 100 pixels
  TIMESCALE=24


  TIMESTEP = 3652.5*TIMESCALE# 1 day
  #TIMESTEP=240
  global self
  def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, mass, name, image, rect, imgH, imgW):
    
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.radius=radius
      self.color = color
      self.mass = mass
      self.name = name
      self.image=image
      self.rect=rect
      self.imgH=imgH
      self.imgW=imgW
    




      self.orbit = []
      self.sun = False
      self.distance_to_sun = 0
    
      self.x_vel = 0
      self.y_vel = 0
      self.revolution = 0
      self.oldx = 0
      self.oldy = 0
      self.newx = 0
      self.newy = 0




  def draw(self, win):
      x = self.x * self.SCALE + WIDTH / 2
      y = self.y * self.SCALE + HEIGHT / 2




      if len(self.orbit) > 2:
          updated_points = []
          for point in self.orbit:
              x, y = point
              x = x * self.SCALE + WIDTH / 2
              y = y * self.SCALE + HEIGHT / 2
              updated_points.append((x, y))




         
          if self.sun==False:
           pygame.draw.lines(win, self.color, False, updated_points, 2)
    
      pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (x, y), self.radius)
      win.blit( self.image, (x-self.imgW,y-self.imgH))
    
      #if not self.sun:
      distance_text = FONT.render(self.name, 1, REAL_WHITE)
     
      revolution_text = FONT.render(str(self.revolution), 1, REAL_WHITE)
      win.blit(distance_text, (x - distance_text.get_width(), y - distance_text.get_height()+10))
      if self.sun==False:
       win.blit(revolution_text, (x - revolution_text.get_width(), y - revolution_text.get_height()))




  def attraction(self, other):
      other_x, other_y = other.x, other.y
      distance_x = other_x - self.x
      distance_y = other_y - self.y
      distance = math.sqrt(distance_x ** 2 + distance_y ** 2)




      if other.sun:
          self.distance_to_sun = distance




      force = self.G * self.mass * other.mass / distance**2
      theta = math.atan2(distance_y, distance_x)
      force_x = math.cos(theta) * force
      force_y = math.sin(theta) * force
      return force_x, force_y




  def update_position(self, planets):
      total_fx = total_fy = 0
      for planet in planets:
          if self == planet:
              continue




          fx, fy = self.attraction(planet)
          total_fx += fx
          total_fy += fy




      self.x_vel += total_fx / self.mass * self.TIMESTEP
      self.y_vel += total_fy / self.mass * self.TIMESTEP




      self.x += self.x_vel * self.TIMESTEP
      self.y += self.y_vel * self.TIMESTEP
    
      self.orbit.append((self.x, self.y))




  def revolutionCount(self, planets):
      if sun.sun==False:
       self.newx = self.x
       self.newy = self.y
       if self.oldy <sun.y:
           if self.newy >=sun.y:
               if self.newx <0:
                   self.revolution+=1

  
                
    
    




def main():
   run = True
   clock = pygame.time.Clock()




 
   global sun
   sunImage=pygame.image.load("./images/sun.png")
   sunImageSize=(35,35)
   sunImage=pygame.transform.scale(sunImage, sunImageSize)
   sunRect=sunImage.get_rect()
   sunimagewidth=sunImage.get_width()
   sunimageheight=sunImage.get_height()




   sunimagewidth=sunimagewidth/2
   sunimageheight=sunimageheight/2
  
   sun = Planet(0, 0, 15, YELLOW, 1.98892 * 10**30, "Sun", sunImage, sunRect, sunimageheight, sunimagewidth)
   sun.sun = True
   def reset():
      global earth
      earthImage=pygame.image.load("./images/earth.jpg")
      earthImageSize=(16,16)
      earthImage=pygame.transform.scale(earthImage, earthImageSize)
      earthRect=earthImage.get_rect()
      earthimagewidth=earthImage.get_width()
      earthimageheight=earthImage.get_height()




      earthimageheight=earthimageheight/2
      earthimagewidth=earthimagewidth/2
    
      earth = Planet(sun.x-0.983292 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 8, BLUE, 5.9742 * 10**24, "Earth", earthImage, earthRect, earthimageheight, earthimagewidth)
    
    
      earth.y_vel = 30.3 * 1000
      #"/home/b/Python Files/images/272_MarsInSight_poster-jpg.jpg"
      global mars
      marsImage=pygame.image.load("./images/272_MarsInSight_poster-jpg.jpg")
      marsRect=marsImage.get_rect()
      marsImageSize=(22,12)
      marsImage=pygame.transform.scale(marsImage, marsImageSize)
      marsimagewidth=marsImage.get_width()
      marsimageheight=marsImage.get_height()




      marsimageheight=marsimageheight/2
      marsimagewidth=marsimagewidth/2




    
    
      mars = Planet(sun.x-1.3814 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 6, RED, 6.39 * 10**23, "Mars", marsImage, marsRect, marsimageheight, marsimagewidth)
      mars.y_vel = 26.50 * 1000
      global vesta
      vestaImage=pygame.image.load("./images/20130918_vesta_true_color_survey_20110820.jpg")
      vestaRect=vestaImage.get_rect()
      vestaImageSize=(4,4)
      vestaImage=pygame.transform.scale(vestaImage, vestaImageSize)
      vestaimagewidth=vestaImage.get_width()
      vestaimageheight=vestaImage.get_height()
      vestaimageheight=vestaimageheight/2
      vestaimagewidth=vestaimagewidth/2
    
      vesta = Planet(sun.x-2.15 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 2, DARK_GREY, 2.589 * 10**20, "Vesta", vestaImage, vestaRect, vestaimageheight, vestaimagewidth)
      vesta.y_vel = 21.204*1000
      global ceres
      ceresImage=pygame.image.load("./images/pia21079-1041.png")
      ceresRect=ceresImage.get_rect()
      ceresImageSize=(4,4)
      ceresImage=pygame.transform.scale(ceresImage, ceresImageSize)
      ceresimagewidth=ceresImage.get_width()
      ceresimageheight=ceresImage.get_height()
      ceresimageheight=ceresimageheight/2
      ceresimagewidth=ceresimagewidth/2




      ceres = Planet(sun.x-2.55 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 2, DARK_GREY, 9.1* 10**20, "Ceres", ceresImage, ceresRect, ceresimageheight, ceresimagewidth)
      ceres.y_vel = 19.36*1000
      global jupiter
      jupiterImage=pygame.image.load("./images/jupiter.jpg")
      jupiterRect=jupiterImage.get_rect()
      jupiterImageSize=(36,20)
      jupiterImage=pygame.transform.scale(jupiterImage, jupiterImageSize)
      jupiterimagewidth=jupiterImage.get_width()
      jupiterimageheight=jupiterImage.get_height()
      jupiterimageheight=jupiterimageheight/2
      jupiterimagewidth=jupiterimagewidth/2




      jupiter = Planet(sun.x-4.9506 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 10, ORANGE, 1.89813 * 10**27, "Jupiter", jupiterImage, jupiterRect, jupiterimageheight, jupiterimagewidth)
      jupiter.y_vel = 13.707*1000
      global saturn
      saturnImage=pygame.image.load("./images/20170927_gill-saturn.jpg")
      saturnRect=saturnImage.get_rect()
      saturnImageSize=(44,18)
      saturnImage=pygame.transform.scale(saturnImage, saturnImageSize)
      saturnimagewidth=saturnImage.get_width()
      saturnimageheight=saturnImage.get_height()
      saturnimageheight=saturnimageheight/2
      saturnimagewidth=saturnimagewidth/2




      saturn = Planet(sun.x-9.0412 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 9, SATURN, 5.683* 10**26, "Saturn", saturnImage, saturnRect, saturnimageheight, saturnimagewidth)
      saturn.y_vel = 10.14*1000
      global uranus
      uranusImage=pygame.image.load("./images/uranus.png")
      uranusRect=uranusImage.get_rect()
      uranusImageSize=(27,16)
      uranusImage=pygame.transform.scale(uranusImage, uranusImageSize)
      uranusimagewidth=uranusImage.get_width()
      uranusimageheight=uranusImage.get_height()
      uranusimageheight=uranusimageheight/2
      uranusimagewidth=uranusimagewidth/2




      uranus = Planet(sun.x-18.2861 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 8, URANUS, 8.681 * 10**25, "Uranus", uranusImage, uranusRect, uranusimageheight, uranusimagewidth)
      uranus.y_vel = 7.13*1000
      global neptune
      neptuneImage=pygame.image.load("./images/neptune.jpg")
      neptuneRect=neptuneImage.get_rect()
      neptuneImageSize=(16,16)
      neptuneImage=pygame.transform.scale(neptuneImage, neptuneImageSize)
      neptuneimagewidth=neptuneImage.get_width()
      neptuneimageheight=neptuneImage.get_height()
      neptuneimageheight=neptuneimageheight/2
      neptuneimagewidth=neptuneimagewidth/2




      neptune = Planet(sun.x-30.33 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 8, NEPTUNE, 1.024 * 10**26, "Neptune", neptuneImage, neptuneRect, neptuneimageheight, neptuneimagewidth)
      neptune.y_vel= 5.37*1000
      global pluto
      plutoImage=pygame.image.load("./images/pluto.png")
      plutoRect=plutoImage.get_rect()
      plutoImageSize=(4,4)
      plutoImage=pygame.transform.scale(plutoImage, plutoImageSize)
      plutoimagewidth=plutoImage.get_width()
      plutoimageheight=plutoImage.get_height()
      plutoimageheight=plutoimageheight/2
      plutoimagewidth=plutoimagewidth/2




      pluto = Planet(sun.x-29.658 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 2, WHITE, 1.31 * 10**22, "Pluto", plutoImage, plutoRect, plutoimageheight, plutoimagewidth)
      pluto.y_vel = 6.113*1000
      global haumea
      haumeaImage=pygame.image.load("./images/haumea.jpg")
      haumeaRect=haumeaImage.get_rect()
      haumeaImageSize=(6,4)
      haumeaImage=pygame.transform.scale(haumeaImage, haumeaImageSize)
      haumeaimagewidth=haumeaImage.get_width()
      haumeaimageheight=haumeaImage.get_height()
      haumeaimageheight=haumeaimageheight/2
      haumeaimagewidth=haumeaimagewidth/2




      haumea = Planet(sun.x-34.647 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 2, DARK_GREY, 4.006*10**21, "Haumea", haumeaImage, haumeaRect, haumeaimageheight, haumeaimagewidth)
      haumea.y_vel = 5.536*1000
      global makemake
      makemakeImage=pygame.image.load("./images/makemake.png")
      makemakeRect=makemakeImage.get_rect()
      makemakeImageSize=(6,4)
      makemakeImage=pygame.transform.scale(makemakeImage, makemakeImageSize)
      makemakeimagewidth=makemakeImage.get_width()
      makemakeimageheight=makemakeImage.get_height()
      makemakeimageheight=makemakeimageheight/2
      makemakeimagewidth=makemakeimagewidth/2




      makemake = Planet(sun.x-38.104 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 2, RED, 3.1* 10**21, "Makemake", makemakeImage, makemakeRect, makemakeimageheight, makemakeimagewidth)
      makemake.y_vel = 5.2*1000
      global eris
      erisImage=pygame.image.load("./images/eso1142a.jpg")
      erisRect=erisImage.get_rect()
      erisImageSize=(6,4)
      erisImage=pygame.transform.scale(erisImage, erisImageSize)
      erisimagewidth=erisImage.get_width()
      erisimageheight=erisImage.get_height()
      erisimageheight=erisimageheight/2
      erisimagewidth=erisimagewidth/2




      eris = Planet(sun.x-38.271*Planet.AU, sun.y, 2, DARK_GREY, 1.6466*10**22, "Eris", erisImage, erisRect, erisimageheight, erisimagewidth)
      eris.y_vel = 5.77*1000
      global sedna
      sedna=Planet(-76.19*Planet.AU, 0, 2, RED, 1*10**22, "Sedna", makemakeImage, makemakeRect, makemakeimageheight, makemakeimagewidth)
      sedna.y_vel=4.644*1000




      cometImage=pygame.image.load("./images/comet.png")
      cometRect=cometImage.get_rect()
      cometImageSize=(3,3)
      cometImage=pygame.transform.scale(cometImage, cometImageSize)
      cometimagewidth=cometImage.get_width()
      cometimageheight=cometImage.get_height()
      cometimageheight=cometimageheight/2
      cometimagewidth=cometimagewidth/2


      #lobal moon
      #moon=Planet(earth.x-0.00257*Planet.AU, 0, 2, REAL_WHITE, 7.342*10**22, "The Moon", cometImage, cometRect, cometimageheight, cometimagewidth)
      #moon.y_vel=earth.y_vel-(1.0757*1000)
     




      global comet
      comet=Planet(sun.x-0.59278*Planet.AU, sun.y, 3, REAL_WHITE, 2.2*10**14, "Halley's Comet", cometImage, cometRect, cometimageheight, cometimagewidth)
      comet.y_vel=54.26*1000
     
      global mercury
      mercuryImage=pygame.image.load("./images/Mercury_in_true_color.jpg")
      mercuryRect=mercuryImage.get_rect()
      mercuryImageSize=(8,8)
      mercuryImage=pygame.transform.scale(mercuryImage, mercuryImageSize)
      mercuryimagewidth=mercuryImage.get_width()
      mercuryimageheight=mercuryImage.get_height()
      mercuryimageheight=mercuryimageheight/2
      mercuryimagewidth=mercuryimagewidth/2




      mercury = Planet(sun.x-0.307499 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 4, DARK_GREY, 3.30 * 10**23, "Mercury", mercuryImage, mercuryRect, mercuryimageheight, mercuryimagewidth)
      mercury.y_vel = 58.97 * 1000
      global venus
      #venusImage=pygame.image.load("./images/venus.png")
      venusImage=pygame.image.load("./images/venus.png")
      venusRect=venusImage.get_rect()
      venusImageSize=(15,15)
      venusImage=pygame.transform.scale(venusImage, venusImageSize)
      venusimagewidth=venusImage.get_width()
      venusimageheight=venusImage.get_height()
      venusimageheight=venusimageheight/2
      venusimagewidth=venusimagewidth/2








      venus = Planet(sun.x-0.718440 * Planet.AU, sun.y, 7, WHITE, 4.8685 * 10**24, "Venus", venusImage, venusRect, venusimageheight, venusimagewidth)
      venus.y_vel = 35.26 * 1000
      global planets
      planets = [sun, earth, mars, vesta, ceres, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto, haumea, makemake, eris, sedna,  comet, mercury, venus]
   reset()


   while run:
    
      clock.tick(30)
      WIN.fill((0, 0, 0))
      pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos
      sun.y_vel=0
      sun.x_vel=0
      FLAG=False
      CLICKFLAG=False
      for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        


          if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                      print("Mercury:", mercury.revolution)
                      print("Venus:", venus.revolution)
                      print("Earth:", earth.revolution)
                      print("Mars:", mars.revolution)
                      print("Vesta:",vesta.revolution)
                      print("Ceres:", ceres.revolution)
                      print("Jupiter:", jupiter.revolution)
                      print("Saturn:", saturn.revolution)
                      print("Uranus:", uranus.revolution)
                      print("Neptune:", neptune.revolution)
                      print("Pluto:", pluto.revolution)
                      print("Haumea:", haumea.revolution)
                      print("Makemake:", makemake.revolution)
                      print("Eris:", eris.revolution)
                      print("Sedna:", sedna.revolution)
                      print("Comet:", comet.revolution)
                      screenFLAG=True
                     
          if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if Planet.ZOOM>=1:
                  if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                      Planet.ZOOM+=1
                      Planet.SCALE=Planet.ZOOM/Planet.AU
                      print(Planet.ZOOM)
            
                    
                  if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                      Planet.ZOOM-=1
                      Planet.SCALE=Planet.ZOOM/Planet.AU
                      print(Planet.ZOOM)
                  if event.key==pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                      Planet.ZOOM*=2
                      Planet.SCALE=Planet.ZOOM/Planet.AU
                  if event.key==pygame.K_RSHIFT:
                      Planet.ZOOM/=2
                      Planet.SCALE=Planet.ZOOM/Planet.AU
                     
                 
                  
              if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                  FLAG=True
              if Planet.TIMESTEP==0 and event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                  FLAG=False
              
              if FLAG==True:
                  Planet.TIMESTEP=0
                  print("Mercury:", mercury.revolution)
                  print("Venus:", venus.revolution)
                  print("Earth:", earth.revolution)
                  print("Mars:", mars.revolution)
                  print("Vesta:",vesta.revolution)
                  print("Ceres:", ceres.revolution)
                  print("Jupiter:", jupiter.revolution)
                  print("Saturn:", saturn.revolution)
                  print("Uranus:", uranus.revolution)
                  print("Neptune:", neptune.revolution)
                  print("Pluto:", pluto.revolution)
                  print("Haumea:", haumea.revolution)
                  print("Makemake:", makemake.revolution)
                  print("Eris:", eris.revolution)
                  print("Sedna:", sedna.revolution)
                  print("Comet:", comet.revolution)




              elif FLAG==False:
                  Planet.TIMESTEP=3600*24
              if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                  Planet.TIMESCALE-=10
                  Planet.TIMESTEP=3600*Planet.TIMESCALE
              if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                  Planet.TIMESCALE+=10
                  Planet.TIMESTEP=3600*Planet.TIMESCALE
                
              if event.key==pygame.K_PAGEUP:
                  Planet.TIMESCALE*=2
                  Planet.TIMESTEP=3600*Planet.TIMESCALE
              if event.key==pygame.K_PAGEDOWN:
                  Planet.TIMESCALE/=2
                  Planet.TIMESTEP=3600*Planet.TIMESCALE
              if event.key==pygame.K_x:
                  run = False
                  print("Mercury:", mercury.revolution)
                  print("Venus:", venus.revolution)
                  print("Earth:", earth.revolution)
                  print("Mars:", mars.revolution)
                  print("Vesta:",vesta.revolution)
                  print("Ceres:", ceres.revolution)
                  print("Jupiter:", jupiter.revolution)
                  print("Saturn:", saturn.revolution)
                  print("Uranus:", uranus.revolution)
                  print("Neptune:", neptune.revolution)
                  print("Pluto:", pluto.revolution)
                  print("Haumea:", haumea.revolution)
                  print("Makemake:", makemake.revolution)
                  print("Eris:", eris.revolution)
                  print("Sedna:", sedna.revolution)
                  print("Comet:", comet.revolution)




              if event.key==pygame.K_r:
                  x=0
                  #initialization function goes here
                  reset()
              if event.key==pygame.K_0:
                  sun.x=0
                  sun.y=0
                  #reset()
              if event.key==pygame.K_1:
                  x=0
              if event.key==pygame.K_2:
                  sun.x=2*Planet.AU
                  sun.y=-1*Planet.AU
                  #reset()
              if event.key==pygame.K_3:
                  sun.x=-2*Planet.AU
                  sun.y=1*Planet.AU
                  #reset()
              if event.key==pygame.K_4:
                  sun.x=2*Planet.AU
                  sun.y=1*Planet.AU
                  #reset()
              if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                  sun.y-=0.01*Planet.AU
              if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                  sun.x-=0.01*Planet.AU
              if event.key==pygame.K_s:
                  sun.y+=0.01*Planet.AU
              if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                  sun.x+=0.01*Planet.AU


          elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              run = False




      for planet in planets:
        
          earth.oldy = earth.y
        
          mars.oldy = mars.y
          vesta.oldy = vesta.y
          ceres.oldy = ceres.y
          jupiter.oldy = jupiter.y
          saturn.oldy = saturn.y
          uranus.oldy =uranus.y
          neptune.oldy = neptune.y
          pluto.oldy = pluto.y
          haumea.oldy = haumea.y
          makemake.oldy = makemake.y
          eris.oldy = eris.y
          sedna.oldy = sedna.y
          comet.oldy=comet.y
          mercury.oldy = mercury.y
          venus.oldy = venus.y
          

          planet.update_position(planets)
          planet.revolutionCount(planets)
          



        
          planet.draw(WIN)
        




      pygame.display.update()




   pygame.quit()








main()
```

`